# How to pass session Cookies in Robot Framework using RequestsLibrary

Tags: python-requests, automated-tests, robotframework

I have been looking for solution regarding passing of session Cookies. Below are my codes in Robot Framework

***Settings***

```
Library           String
Library           OperatingSystem
Library           Collections
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           requests
```

***Variables ***

```
${base_url}       https://api.company.net
${email}          operator1@datavalidation.org
${password}       Company2021
&{headers}        Content-Type=application/json    X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

*** Test Cases ***

```
Session | Login
    Login

Session | My
    My_Profile
```

*** Keywords ***

```
Login

    &{auth_dict}=    Create Dictionary    email    ${email}    password    ${password}
    Create Session    loginsession    ${base_url}    verify=True
    ${response}=    POST On Session    loginsession    /session/login    json=${auth_dict}
    Log    ${response.json()}
    
    #VALIDATION
    ${status}=    Convert To String    ${response.status_code}    
    Should Be Equal    ${status}    200
    ${body}=    Convert To String    ${response.content}    
    Should Contain    ${body}    true    #"status"
    Should Contain    ${body}    abf60345-4043-4f1e-94b0-a307f9209beb    #"uuid"
    
    #GET SESSION COOKIE VALUE
    ${Session_cookie}=    Get From Dictionary    ${response.cookies}    PHPSESSID
    &{Cookie_value}=    Create Dictionary    PHPSESSID    ${Session_cookie}
    Set Suite Variable    &{Cookie_value}

My_Profile
    Create Session    mysession    ${base_url}    cookies=&{Cookie_value}    verify=True
    ${response}=    GET On Session    mysession    /session/me
    Log    ${response.json()}
```

As you can see, I extracted the **Cookie** in (Session | Login)  and tried to pass it onto the following **test cast** (Session | My). Although, I tried to follow the syntax, but still I'm unable to access the API with the Session Cookie. I look forward for open suggestions.

Thank you.

I got the following output-

```
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : 
POST Request : url=https://api.company.net/session/login 
 path_url=/session/login 
 headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '68', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
 body=b'{"email": "operator1@company.org", "password": "Company2021"}' 
 
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : 
POST Response : url=https://api.company.net/session/login 
 status=200, reason=OK 
 headers={'Date': 'Thu, 25 Feb 2021 17:40:50 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json,...'PHP/7.2.34', 'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=567ta9n28tudq00f09r9g33qfc; path=/',, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Access....'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000;'} 
 body={"ok":true,"status":200,"data":{"uuid":"abf60345-4043-4f1e-94b0-a307f9209beb",...}
 
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : ${response} = <Response [200]>
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : {'ok': True, 'status': 200, 'data': {'uuid': 'abf60345-4043-4f1e-94b0-a307f9209beb',...} 
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : ${status} = 200
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : ${body} = {"ok":true,"status":200,"data":{"uuid":"abf60345-4043-4f1e-94b0-a307f9209beb",...}
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : ${Session_cookie} = 567ta9n28tudq00f09r9g33qfc
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : &{Cookie_value} = { PHPSESSID=567ta9n28tudq00f09r9g33qfc }
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : &{Cookie_value} = { PHPSESSID=567ta9n28tudq00f09r9g33qfc }
Ending test:   Operator.Session | Login

Starting test: Operator.Session | Me
20210225 18:40:51.355 :  INFO : Creating Session using : alias=mesession, url=https://api.company.net, headers={}, cookies={'PHPSESSID': '567ta9n28tudq00f09r9g33qfc'}, auth=None, timeout=None, proxies=None, verify=True,                     debug=0 
20210225 18:40:51.555 :  INFO : 
GET Request : url=https://api.company.net/session/me 
 path_url=/session/me 
 headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=567ta9n28tudq00f09r9g33qfc'} 
 body=None 
 
20210225 18:40:51.555 :  INFO : 
GET Response : url=https://api.company.net/session/me 
 status=403, reason=FORBIDDEN 
 headers={'Date': 'Thu, 25 Feb 2021 17:40:50 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', .... *"} 
 body={"ok":false,"status":403,"data":null,"errors":"5.95.67.44 not allowed"} 
 
20210225 18:40:51.586 :  FAIL : HTTPError: 403 Client Error: FORBIDDEN for url: https://api.company.net/session/me
Ending test:   Operator.Session | Me
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by Creating a session in the first `Test Case` and the pass the `alias` to the following `Test Case` (Instead of extracting the Cookies and passing them in the next case.)

Here is the way I did it-

*** Variables ***

```
${base_url}       https://api.company.net
${email}          operator1@datavalidation.org
${password}       Company2021
&{headers}        Content-Type=application/json    X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

*** Test Cases ***

```
Session | Login
    &{auth_dict}=    Create Dictionary    email    ${email}    password    ${password}
    Create Session    api    ${base_url}    verify=True
    ${test_uri}    Set Variable    /session/login
    ${response}    POST On Session    api    ${test_uri}    json=${auth_dict}    headers=${headers}


Session | Me
    ${response}    GET On Session    api    /session/me    headers=&{headers}
```